# Iterate number in '.each' jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script like below, and I want to set the incrementing number for  `kode` on `name='service_id["+kode+"]'`. The problem is the number was not incrementing yet, just shown 1.

How can I set the incrementing number of row?

Here is my script:

```
function getCorporateService(id){
    // get data and parsing to column
    $.get("{{ url('salesorder/service')}}/"+id, function(data){
        console.log(id);
        console.log(data);

        var kode = 0;
        $.each(data, function (index, element){
            kode++;
            $br = "<tr id='item'>";
            $br += "<td> <input class='input-small' type='text' id='order_identifier' name='order_identifier' readonly></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='service_id["+id+"]' name='service_id["+kode+"]' value='"+element.service_name+"' readonly></td>";
            $br += "<td><select id='order_type["+id+"]' name='order_type["+id+"]'> <option> - </option> <option value='add'>Add</option> <option value='change'>Change</option> <option value='cancel'>Cancel</option> </select></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='select_plan["+id+"]' name='select_plan["+kode+"]'></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-mini' type='text' id='qty["+id+"]' name='qty["+kode+"]' value='1' onChange='getTotalPrice("+id+")'></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='unit_price["+id+"]' name='unit_price["+kode+"]' onChange='getTotalPrice("+id+")'></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='total_price["+id+"]' name='total_price["+kode+"]' onChange='getTotalPrice("+id+")'></td>";
            $br += "<td><textarea class='input-small' id='notes["+id+"]' name='notes["+kode+"]'></textarea></td>";
            $br += "</tr>";

            $(".corporatesvc").append($br);

        });
     });
}
```

Comment: So, just use `index`?

Comment: if you want kode to increment you must assign the value back to kode like this kode=kode+1, and furthermore you wouldn't have to use an incrementing variable you could use the index directly

Comment: @GraveyardQueen: He's already incrementing `kode`:  `kode++;`

Comment: doesn't he have to assign it back to the code variable like this, kode=kode++

Comment: @Cerbrus can you explain how to use `index` ? i just try `index` but it show 0 value, still not increment yet.

Comment: @GraveyardQueen: [No he does not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/26k41698(v=vs.94).aspx).

Comment: @rafitio: Just use `+index+` instead of `+kode+`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with your JSON data you are receiving from response.

See the working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
    "service_name": "Test 1",
    "Major": "Physics"
  }, {
    "service_name": "Test 2",
    "Major": "Chemistry"
  }, {
    "service_name": "Test 3",
    "Major": "Mathematics"
  }];
  var id = 1;
  var kode = 0;
  $.each(data, function(index, element) {
    kode++;
    $br = "<tr id='item'>";
    $br += "<td> <input class='input-small' type='text' id='order_identifier' name='order_identifier' readonly></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='service_id[" + id + "]' name='service_id[" + kode + "]' value='" + element.service_name + "' readonly></td>";
    $br += "<td><select id='order_type[" + id + "]' name='order_type[" + id + "]'> <option> - </option> <option value='add'>Add</option> <option value='change'>Change</option> <option value='cancel'>Cancel</option> </select></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='select_plan[" + id + "]' name='select_plan[" + kode + "]'></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-mini' type='text' id='qty[" + id + "]' name='qty[" + kode + "]' value='1' onChange='getTotalPrice(" + id + ")'></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='unit_price[" + id + "]' name='unit_price[" + kode + "]' onChange='getTotalPrice(" + id + ")'></td>";
    $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='total_price[" + id + "]' name='total_price[" + kode + "]' onChange='getTotalPrice(" + id + ")'></td>";
    $br += "<td><textarea class='input-small' id='notes[" + id + "]' name='notes[" + kode + "]'></textarea></td>";
    $br += "</tr>";

    $(".corporatesvc").append($br);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="corporatesvc">

</div>
```

See code snippet in jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/z6gbcutg/2/